# Flutter PopScope not working when clicking Back on android device

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I am trying to make it work that when I click on back button on my Android device to just pop current screen and go to previous one, right now it exits app completely when i click on back button from Detail screen. I am using PopScope in Detail screen and set the canPop to true.

This is where I set my Navigation

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
 .....
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF12142d),
      appBar: MyAppBar(
          searchTextController: searchTextController,
          updateSearchText: updateSearchText),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentIndex,
        children: [
          Navigator(
            onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Search(
                onSearchCompleted: updateSearchData,
                roomsController: roomsController,
                bathroomsController: bathroomsController,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Navigator(
            onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomeScreen(
                searchCriteria: searchCriteria,
                searchText: searchText,
                showAppBar: false,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Navigator(
            onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const Wishlist(),
            ),
          ),
          Navigator(
            onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const OptionsTab(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF12142d),
          selectedItemColor: const Color(0xFFB98B54),
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0.0,
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints:
                      const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 30, maxWidth: 30),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/search.svg',
                    color: _currentIndex == 0
                        ? const Color(0xFFB98B54)
                        : Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                label: ""),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints:
                      const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 30, maxWidth: 30),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/home.svg',
                    color: _currentIndex == 1
                        ? const Color(0xFFB98B54)
                        : Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                label: ""),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints:
                      const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 30, maxWidth: 30),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/heart.svg',
                    color: _currentIndex == 2
                        ? const Color(0xFFB98B54)
                        : Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                label: ""),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints:
                      const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 30, maxWidth: 30),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/icons/settings.svg',
                    color: _currentIndex == 3
                        ? const Color(0xFFB98B54)
                        : Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                label: ""),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Home Screen :

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic>? searchCriteria;
  final String? searchText;
  final bool showAppBar;
  const HomeScreen(
      {super.key,
      this.searchCriteria,
      this.searchText,
      required this.showAppBar});
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  .....
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: widget.showAppBar ? AppBar() : null,
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF12142d),
      body: isLoading
          ? const Center(child: MyCircularProgressIndicator())
          : properties.isEmpty
              ? const Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "no search results",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                )
              : ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: properties.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final property = properties[index];
                    return ListingCard(
                      property: property,
                      onLearnMoreTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => DetailScreen(id: property.id),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
    );
  }
}
```

and Detail Screen, I can go back via icon in App bar:

```
class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  final PropertyType? propertyType;
  final Location? location;
  final List<SellingType>? sellingTypes;
  final List<Extra>? extras;

  const DetailScreen(
      {Key? key,
      required this.id,
      this.propertyType,
      this.location,
      this.sellingTypes,
      this.extras})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DetailScreen> createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
  void myDummyFunction() {
    //print("Button was pressed!");
  }

  late final PageController _pageController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: true,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Color(0xFFB98B54)),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the below code inside the PopScope widget.

```
PopScope(
    canPop: true,
     onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
       Navigator.of(context).pop();
     },
    child: "your widget",
  )
```

Comment: That also doesn't work for me..

Comment: Remove canPop and try

Comment: still doesnt work